# Getting wrong date (wrong offset) from PostgresDB when querying with doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, timezone-offset

I am totally confused about tz (timezones) and datetypes in Symfony and Doctrine.
We are using Symfony 5 and PostgresSQL for the database. In the database we’re using timestamptz for all dates and in the entities we are explizit defining all dates as datetimetz.

@ORM\Column(type="**datetimetz**", nullable=true)

When we create a query with the doctrine querybuilder (createQuery) we’re always losing our saved offset (timezone) from the database. Example: in the database we have:

```
Date: 2021-05-10 00:06:35
Offset: 2.0
```

As a result from the query we get:

```
[date] => 2021-05-09 22:06:35.000000
[timezone_type] => 1
[timezone] => +00:00
```

Btw.: we got the same result when using the repository (getRepository) instead of querying directly.

My question: where did my date get converted and why? Will it be at the database site or on the php level?

Btw. 2: the database default offset is set to **Europe/Berlin** and the php side as well with **date_default_timezone_set**.

Comment: Good read on how to handle this: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#handling-different-timezones-with-the-datetime-type

Answer (score 0):

The mass with **timezones** TZ in postgres is not to have it, it is to handle it in the complete environment. Especially in Symfony(PHP) we need to add the saved timezone to every date.

Example for writing:

```
$booking->setUpdated(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')));
```

Example for reading:

```
date_timezone_set(@$this->getInserted(), timezone_open('Europe/Berlin'));
```

That's my solution.